# Get and display limited no featured products by category in a single row

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a woo commerce wordpress template, i have different categories for featured products. Getting products and displaying them on front page is fine but issue is when i call products by category all products are displayed in a row of that category but i just wanna display limited products as I am new to PHP I do not know how to control the loop
Here is the code:

```
<section class="products">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="h2 upp align-center"> Hybrid devices</h2>
    <hr class="offset-lg">

    <div class="row">

        <?php $query_args = array (
        
        'category' => array('hybrid-devices'),
    );
    $products = wc_get_products($query_args) ;
    global $post;
    $columns = wc_get_loop_prop('columns');
        ?>
        <div class="woocommerce columns-<?php echo esc_attr( $columns ); ?>">
<?php
woocommerce_product_loop_start();
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $post = get_post($product->get_id());
    setup_postdata($post);
    wc_get_template_part('content', 'product');
}
wp_reset_postdata();
woocommerce_product_loop_end();
?>
</div>

           
</div>
    <div class="align-right align-center-xs">
      <hr class="offset-sm">
      <a href="./store/"> <h5 class="upp">View all devices </h5> </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want only X amount of products, and they should not be featured.

If so, I think this query should work:

```
query_args = array (
    'category' => array('hybrid-devices'),
    'limit' => 6, // ... or how many you want
    'featured' => false, // Exclude featured products
);
```

Check this page in the WooCommerce wiki for more info about the WooCommerce products query: [wc_get_products and WC_Product_Query](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query)